# SQL How do I get Tables from Microsoft SQL Server Query Files?

Tags: sql

I need to add a few tables to my SQL Server Management Studio. We were given this link to the Udemy SQL Training Class Code
http://knowlton-group.com/sql-training-class-resource/ . The files are compressed Microsoft SQL Server Query Files.
What do I need to do to get these tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file I see there is a *.ZIP file. If you're using Windows, you can just download the ZIP file. Double click on it and Windows will open it as if you're looking at a folder. In that view, you'll see two *.SQL files. You can drag-and-drop these files to any other location on your computer. Once you've done that, you can just open them in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: How do I open them in SQL Server Management Studio? Will SQL automatically update with the table on the explorer view?